# Помогите сделать триггер в SQL , на запрет повторяющихся номеров телефона в базе данных

Tags: sql, триггер

Помогите пожалуйста сделать триггер на запрет повторяющихся номеров телефона в SQL
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужен именно триггер? Ограничения не хватит?

Comment: А телефон `8 (910) 233-5489` должен ли считаться повторяющимся?

Comment: Нужен именно триггер,не должен

Comment: Надо чтобы триггер , запрещал ввод одинаковых номеров телеофна

Comment: Такие задачи не решаются триггерами. Для этого существуют уникальные индексы. А учебные задания у нас вообще оффтоп.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION phone_check() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees WHERE phone_number = NEW.phone_number) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Есть такой номер';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_phone BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE phone_check();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @ЕвгенийШапошников [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).